# QGIS Unchecking Categorized Layers

Tags: qgis, style

I've got a Layer out of an Shapefile with a lot different Attribute. 
I colored them using properties->Style->categorized with random colours.
Now there are about 800 different colours. It looks something ike this. (It's in german).

[image]

So now if, let's say, I only want to see the second colour "abita Energie Ottenberg GmbH" on the map, the only way to do that is to uncheck all 800 other colours manually. I can't select more to uncheck them together.

Is there an easy way to do that? I hope you can help me.

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Daniel3110! Which QGIS version are you using?

Comment: I am using QGIS 2.14.3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [QGIS 2.14 onwards](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/NEWS#L216), you can *right-click* on any style item and select `Hide All Items`:

[image: Hide All Items]

Then select whichever colours you would like to have shown.

---

*Tested on QGIS 2.14.3 for Win7 64-bit.*

Comment: The best way to say _thanks_ here is accepting the answer that helped you to solve the problem.

Comment: @Daniel3110 - Most welcome, glad it worked :)